# How to serialize Dictionary<string, string> through WCF?

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have a data contract with a data member typed as `Dictionary<string, string>`.

The generated web service reference exposes this as a member with the type `ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[]`.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this page in the WCF documentation (which is much more recent than this question): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts

Answer (score 24, accepted):

WCF only serializes *structure*, because what ends up on the wire must be self-contained enough to be useful for *any* client, not just .NET clients.

Some client developed on a different platform may not share the concept of a 'dictionary', so it would be too constraining to serialize a Dictionary to a representation that carries an implicit knowledge about the underlying class.

The client may not even be object-oriented.

A Dictionary is more than *structure* - it also contains behavior (e.g. when you assign to a key that already exists, you overwrite that key, etc.) and that behavior cannot travel across the wire.

In other words, Dictionaries and many other .NET types are not interoperable, so WCF will not attempt to preserve them in a `ServiceContract`.

You would probably be better off designing a custom `DataContract` for your data.

Comment: That doesn't mean the client proxy can't be generated to convert the data back into a dictionary. What does Visual Studio's "Configure Service Reference" dialog's "Dictionary Collection Type" option do when set to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary then?

Answer (score 5):

As WCF has to convert everything to XML, it has to fit as XML... Collections are generally converted to arrays.

A Dictionary is prety hard to represent as xml, that's why you have this type on the other side. You can specify SvcUtil.exe to use specific collections instead of arrays in the generated proxy code, but I'm not sure it will work for a Dictionary. I would say that you should avoid using a Dictionary here, and use a simpler Collection.

What I would do is create my own data type, [DataContract] it, make it have two fields of type String, then make a Collection of these that you fill with everthing you find in the Dictionary. Then sent that Collection trough the wire, then convert it back to a Dictionary on the other side.

Comment: isn't it just something like a sequence of <entry key="blah">de dah</entry>?

Comment: @Kenny: no, the standard DataContractSerializer doesn't support attributes on XML nodes (for performance reasons)

Comment: @kenny : frankly. yes. and there are a lot of people out there who wrote serializable dictionaries, using very natural key and value xml elements. a dictionary is just a list of pairs. the only valid argument is the one of Mark Seemann about behavior. But a dictionary is certainly not hard to represent in xml. Also python serializes dictionaries just fine, using the same representation as the code itself ! just do `str(mydict)` to get it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it.. The operation contract is actually a string. I escape the json string to keep it a string. I then in the web method unescape the string and parse it into a dictionary using NewtonSoftJson I used Dictionary but you could also do Dictionary if you wanted. Hope this is useful...

I used NewtonSoft Json library...

c# code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void testMethod(string jsonData)
    {
        string data = Uri.UnescapeDataString(jsonData);
        Dictionary<string, string> x = jsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in x)
        {

        }
    }
```

JSCode

```
var Data = {
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    someString: "somedata"
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Service1.svc/testMethod",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 1000000,               
    data:  '{"jsonData": "' + escape(JSON.stringify(Data)) + '"}',
    error: function(error) {
    },
    success: function (data) {
    },
});
```