# passing Dictionary in WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to serialize Dictionary<string, string> through WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510185/how-to-serialize-dictionarystring-string-through-wcf)

How to pass a dictionary in a method in WCf ...
I'm doing this

```
public void SendData(Dictionary<string, string > data)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

When I access it as 192.X.X.X//Akhil/service.svc/SendData?data={}
here What/How should I pass arguments  in data...some example please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate your proxy (Say, "TestProxy") then do:

```
TestProxy.YourServiceClient client = new TestProxy.YourServiceClient();

Dictionary<string, string> testDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

testDict.Add("test", "test1");

client.SendData(testDict);
```

WCF will serialize your Dictionary with no problem.  The problem here is that you are trying to access your WCF service as if you exposed it as a REST Service through an HTTP Get request.  I'm pretty sure based on your question, you aren't exposing this as a REST service.  If you want to be able to do Get Requests, then google .Net WCF REST.

*Note: you might also want to look into the Request/Response SOA pattern, it's going to save a bunch of trouble down the road.

**Update:**

Here are some links that might point you in the right direction, you'll probably want to expose your WCF service as a JSON endpoint.

[JSON / REST Link](http://dotnetninja.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/rest-service-with-wcf-and-json/)

Search Dictionary in this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) to get some details on alternatives and gotchas in WCF JSON.

Hope these help.  I have never done an Iphone app so I don't have any source code to give you.

Comment: Hi CKH Thanks for help... 
I want to send post data from Iphone.
I have to send a dictionary(K-V pairs) with 8 k-v pairs.
I have to receive this dictionary in WCF ...please just help me how will handle it.
i m really sorry if this is something stupid...please help me by some code if possible.

Comment: No, not stupid at all.  I've updated my post above with some links to help you out.