# How do I retrieve a Dictionary data type in a web form?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that returns a Dictionary object. I have created an ASP .NET Web Application and added a web form to test this service. I have added my WCF service reference in the web application. Now, while writing the code for Button1_Click in web form, I am not able to access the Dictionary object that my service returns. The code is as shown below:
Please suggest a solution asap.
Thanks.

```
`using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using WebApplication1.wsHashOps;  

namespace WebApplication1  
{   
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page   
    {   
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
        {

      }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {
            string input = TextBox1.Text;
            Service1 client = new Service1();
            string data = "";



            Dictionary<int, string> hh = client.getWsHashOperations(input);

            string input = TextBox1.Text;    
            Service1 client = new Service1();    
            string data = "";    
            Dictionary<int, string> hh = client.getWsHashOperations(input);        
}        
}        
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebApplication1.wsHashOps.ArrayOfKeyValueOfintstringKeyValueOfintstring[]' to 'Systems.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<int,string>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    KeyValuePair<int,string>[] hh = client.getWsHashOperations(input);

    string input = TextBox1.Text;    
    Service1 client = new Service1();    
    string data = "";    
    KeyValuePair<int,string>[] hh2 = client.getWsHashOperations(input);
```

You can't declare two variables with the same name. Rename one of them.
Also, looks like it resolves to KeyValuePair arrays based on your error message. Try the above

You can also use the var key word in cases like these

```
var hh = client.getWsHashOperations(input);
```

This will resolve the data type for you implicitly, while still maintaining type safety

Comment: Sorry that was a typing error. There is only one hh object. Also I tried using KeyValuePair<int,string> instead of Dictionary<int,string> but is still shows the same error.

Comment: Ok, can you post the wcf method?

Comment: Yes I know I can use var, but then how to extract each dictionary value from the var data type?

Comment: Can't post it here, its too long. But i can tell you that it the return type of the wcf method is Dictionary<int,string>.

Comment: Ok, I believe this could be due to wcf having some difficulties serializing Dictionaries. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510185/how-to-serialize-dictionarystring-string-through-wcf/1510245#1510245