# using dictionary with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to return a dictionary over WCF

```
    public Dictionary<LanguageList> GetLanguageSettingList()
    {
        Repository exrepo = new Repository(this.ConnectionString);

        return exrepo.GetLanguageSettingList();
    }


public partial class LanguageList
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Id { get; set; }
}
```

The error reads `Error  1   Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,TValue>' requires 2 type arguments   c:\users\xxxxx\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\service\service\service.svc.cs 74  16  SaService`
. I'm not sure what else I have to pass to return a dictionary any help? Thanks M

Comment: Dictionary has two type arguments not one. Besides, is LanguageList type serializable?

Comment: the LanguageList  is just return as a list from a Stored proc but my application needs it as a dictionary

Comment: Iv been reading this to no luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510185/how-to-serialize-dictionarystring-string-through-wcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax have errors in code.
This is what you really need:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> GetLanguageSettingList()
    {
        Repository exrepo = new Repository(this.ConnectionString);

        return exrepo.GetLanguageSettingList().Where(c=>c.Id!=null).ToDictionary(c=>c.Id.Value, c=>c.Language);
    }


public partial class LanguageList
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general if you are going to return data via WCF. The data class defined. ( In this case LanguageList ) should be decorated with a [DataContract]
and the members with DataMember

```
[DataContract]
public class X
{
    [DataMember]
    int MyProp {get;set;}
}
```

give that a go.