# Why my WCF Service returning ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring instead of Dictionary<string, string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I want to know the reason behind this, why my wcf service method return type is changed from  `Dictionary<string, string>`  to `ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring`. Is there any way to get the originial return type `Dictionary<string, string>` . I want to know the reason why it does so, Is this due to Serialization?. I'm using Json.Net library in wcf service for some other method.

Comment: what is your client?

Comment: asp.net web application is client

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510185/how-to-serialize-dictionarystring-string-through-wcf

Comment: Isolate the service interface to another assembly. Use that assembly as a reference for both the service implementation and its clients.

Comment: what do u mean by this ?